# Format special text with in a HTML textarea

Tags: html, css, formatting

I am developing a web editor for SQL, I would like to be able to style special SQL text with in text (select, create, from) differently from other texts, as a user types.
Is this possible in HTML?
Is there a third party libary/plugin I can use for this?

Comment: Thanks @Surreal Dreams for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting inside a textarea is minimal at best.  You might try the approach that Stack Overflow uses, which is to let your user input in a textarea and then display another box with the input formatted.  This is done at SO using [Google Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html).  This includes SQL formatting as well as a list of other languages, detected and formatted automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Try [EditErea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/), it has built-it SQL highlighting support.